# Embedded 360 Videos from YouTube not replaying correctly on iOS browsers

Tags: ios, youtube, html5-video, 360-virtual-reality

Im recording 360° videos for my real estate agency and embed the videos on my wordpress website on the various listings. However after being uploading new videos for properties for about 3 days now. Ive realized they dont play correctly on iOS devices.

Basically you cant move the camera around with your finger or by moving the device around.

Android does work, but iOS doesnt. Tried different browsers too its something to do with how ioS or the player iOS uses when playing a youtube video.

How can I fix this problem? As its a massive issue that I must fix somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Example link: https://66property.com/estate_property/studio-for-rent-at-srithana-condo-on-high-floor-w-mountain-view/

Video works fine on android/desktop/mac/windows but not if on iOS. Tested Safari and Chrome. Both didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a limitation for some time on Mobile devices unfortunately - embedded 360 videos require the YouTube App to play. See note from YouTube (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en):

> To watch 180° or  360° videos, you need the latest version of Chrome, Opera, Firefox, or MS Edge. On mobile devices, use the latest version of the YouTube app.

It does appear to work on Android devices when embedded now, but on iOS this seems to still be a restriction.

Comment: This is quite annoying. As we'd like to start using real 360 Videos for our website and now instead will have to change our strategy slightly. Its 2020 apple! Get with it!